Observation angle in KITTI dataset
I'm working with Neural Scene Graphs which uses KITTI and Virtual-KITTI datasets for demonstration of their method (they render 3D objects in desired locations via their NeRF representations).
At the moment, I'm trying to replace the VKITTI data with my own data consisting of images (stereo pair) and 3D labels as given in pose.txt file. The information (required in pose.txt) are : object location in world frame and object location in camera frame. The various data fields are explained towards the bottom in this page : https://europe.naverlabs.com/research/computer-vision/proxy-virtual-worlds-vkitti-2/.
I am confused about the term observation angle (column 4). It simply says:

KITTI-like observation angle of the object in [-pi..pi]

Some links online seem to suggest it's a combination of object heading and angular location of a 3D object (as shown in the image below)

So to clarify my understanding, I tried to compute this using those angles shown in the image and can't seem to get it right. Here for example, I consider a frame with only one object (the blue car) whose location is given in pose.txt as shown in image (table) below. This object only has YAW and ROLL PITCH are zero.

Extrinsic for first frame gives the location of the camera:



frame
cameraID
r1_1
r1_2
r1_3
t1
r2_1
r2_2
r2_3
t2
r3_1
r3_2
r3_3
t3
0
0
0
1




0
0
0.9597942
-0.01231958
-0.2804343
-1.723701
0.008060207
0.9998341
-0.01633679
114.6418
0.280589
0.0134196
0.9597342
0.449038
0
0
0
1


0
0
0.9597942
-0.01231958
-0.2804343
-2.256426
0.008060207
0.9998341
-0.01633679
114.6418
0.280589
0.0134196
0.9597342
0.449038
0
0
0
1



The camera location from extrinsics is : [-1.723701, 114.6418, 0.449038]
The object location (center of bottom face) : [0.8166, -113, 13.16]
For the ray angle, we only need x-z coordinates (for object and camera): dz = 12.71 and dx = 2.5403 which gives theta_ray = 1.3635.  The given orientation of the car is (rotation_world_space_y) = 2.63. The resulting value for theta_l = 2*pi - 2.63 - 1.37 = 2.28   which is different than the expected value of alpha = 2.622 (given by the fourth column of pose.txt).
My question is what is observation angle alpha and how to verify its value for the given KITTI dataset?

I have no clue but would ask: since they speak of "observation angle", is the object not supposed to be directly in front of the camera (object center on optical axis)? then all this angling would be less ambiguous.

@ChristophRackwitz  The objects (mostly cars and trucks) can be anywhere in the field of view of the camera. This dataset was recorded primarily for Visual Odometry and VSLAM tasks.

random github issue discussing the same: https://github.com/NVlabs/Deep_Object_Pose/issues/86 -- some readme that mentions it a few times but I can't tell if it's explained or inferrable: https://github.com/bostondiditeam/kitti/blob/master/resources/devkit_object/readme.txt -- someone's attempt to describe the parameters (IDK if he's right): https://medium.com/@abdulhaq.ah/explain-label-file-of-kitti-dataset-738528de36f4

@ChristophRackwitz  Oh this post kind of "mentioned" the definition of observation angle (The image comes from that post). Since the angles don't add up (as shown in image), I doubt if the association of observation angle to the angle shown in image.

In description of alpha on the github_link mentions it to be same as what is shown in the image above. The
alpha also considers the vector from the camera center to the object center, to compute the relative orientation of the object with respect to the camera. For example, a car which is facing along the X-axis of the camera coordinate system corresponds to rotation_y=0, no matter where it is located in the X/Z plane, while alpha is zero only, when this object is located along the Z-axis of the camera. When moving the car away from the Z-axis, the observation angle will change.
